# CompliationLock throws HttpException when registering areas for ASP.NET MVC unit tests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

The moment I added a unit test to my ASP.NET MVC application to test some of the area routing, I got an `HttpException` coming out of the `System.Web.Complication.CompilationLock` type initializer with the following stack trace.

```
System.Web.HttpException : The type initializer for 'System.Web.Compilation.CompilationLock' threw an exception.
  ----> System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'System.Web.Compilation.CompilationLock' threw an exception.
  ----> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()
at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()
at System.Web.Mvc.TypeCacheUtil.FilterTypesInAssemblies(IBuildManager buildManager, Predicate`1 predicate)
at System.Web.Mvc.TypeCacheUtil.GetFilteredTypesFromAssemblies(String cacheName, Predicate`1 predicate, IBuildManager buildManager)
at System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(RouteCollection routes, IBuildManager buildManager, Object state)
at System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(Object state)
at System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()
at StpWeb.MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) in Global.asax.cs: line 16
at StpWeb.Tests.RoutesTest.TestFixtureSetUp() in RoutesTest.cs: line 11
--TypeInitializationException
at System.Web.Compilation.CompilationLock.GetLock(ref Boolean gotLock)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
--NullReferenceException
at System.Web.Compilation.CompilationLock..cctor()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else that followed the MVC [Areas tutorials on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461420(v=VS.100).aspx), you will find an issue if you ever add unit tests to the web application you created.

It tells you to add `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` to the `RegisterRoutes` method. Unfortunately, that is a static method that gets upset when called from unit tests.

Instead, register areas within `Application_Start`, right before the `RegisterRoutes` call you just modified. If you call `RegisterRoutes` first, UrlParameter.Optional appears to stop working in area routes (keeps working in non-area routes, though).

```
protected void Application_Start() {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Comment: I could have saved a few hours if I found [this person](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=4915)  with the same issue on the MVC CodePlex site. The comments to that issue offer the same solution.

Comment: This appears to be set up by default within Global.asax.cs in VS2010 when you create an empty MVC2 project.